# Create JAR file from large IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am trying to create a JAR for my IntelliJ project.

The problem that I am facing is that most tutorials such as: [TUTORIAL EXAMPLE](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/) show that in order to generate the JAR file I have to go to this [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEZgt.png) and select the JAR file but for me the option to create a JAR file does not exist.

Is there any other way I could go about creating the JAR file?

Comment: Well, it might be time to have a look into build tools like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Isn't that a maven project?